# auto increment `trackingcode` column every insert to database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

I created a field on my database named `trackingcode` and here's and example of the code that it generates:

[image: Example]

Now I wanted to start to `TS-001` when I generate and so on...

Example:

```html
TS-001
TS-002
TS-003
TS-004
SO ON...
```

I'm not sure where to start, I tried setting the `trackingcode` to TS-000 and then change the mysql column to AUTO_INCREMENT but it didn't work.

Anyway here's my default code that generates random numbers:

```js
<?php
//insert.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pcrequest");
if(isset($_POST["reqname"]))
{
 $length = 3;
 $trackingcode = 'TS-' . substr(str_shuffle("0123456789"), 0, $length);
 $req_date = $_POST["req_date"];
 $reqname = $_POST["reqname"];
 $date = $_POST["date"];
 $empname = $_POST["empname"];
 $position = $_POST["position"];
 $account = $_POST["account"];
 $platform = $_POST["platform"];
 $processor = $_POST["processor"];
 $ram = $_POST["ram"];
 $monitor = $_POST["monitor"];
 $phone = $_POST["phone"];
 $phonetype = $_POST["phonetype"];
 $headset = $_POST["headset"];
 $req_table = $_POST["req_table"];
 $req_chair = $_POST["req_chair"];
 $approval = $_POST["approval"];
 $status = $_POST["status"];
 $query = '';
 

  for($count = 0; $count<count($reqname); $count++)
  {
  $req_date_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_date[$count]);
  $reqname_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $reqname[$count]);
  $date_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $date[$count]);
  $empname_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $empname[$count]);
  $position_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $position[$count]);
  $account_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $account[$count]);
  $platform_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $platform[$count]);
  $processor_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $processor[$count]);
  $ram_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $ram[$count]);
  $monitor_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $monitor[$count]);
  $phone_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $phone[$count]);
  $phonetype_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $phonetype[$count]);
  $headset_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $headset[$count]);
  $req_table_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_table[$count]);
  $req_chair_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_chair[$count]);
  $approval_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $approval[$count]);
  $status_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $status[$count]);
  if($req_date_clean != '' && $reqname_clean != '' && $date_clean != '' && $empname_clean != '' && $position_clean != '' && $account_clean != '' && $platform_clean != '' && $processor_clean != '' && $ram_clean != '' && $monitor_clean != '' && $phone_clean != '' && $phonetype_clean != '' && $headset_clean != '' && $req_table_clean != '' && $req_chair_clean != '' && $approval_clean != '' && $status_clean != '')
  {
   $query .= '
   INSERT INTO request(trackingcode, req_date, reqname, date, empname, position, account, platform, processor, ram, monitor, phone, phonetype, headset, req_table, req_chair, approval, status) 
   VALUES("'.$trackingcode.'", "'.$req_date_clean.'", "'.$reqname_clean.'", "'.$date_clean.'", "'.$empname_clean.'", "'.$position_clean.'", "'.$account_clean.'", "'.$platform_clean.'", "'.$processor_clean.'", "'.$ram_clean.'", "'.$monitor_clean.'", "'.$phone_clean.'", "'.$phonetype_clean.'", "'.$headset_clean.'", "'.$req_table_clean.'", "'.$req_chair_clean.'", "'.$approval_clean.'", "'.$status_clean.'"); 
   ';
  }

}

 if($query != '')
 {
  if(mysqli_multi_query($connect, $query))
  {
   echo 'Successfuly Sent!';
  }
  else
  {
   echo 'Error';
  }
 }
 else
 {
  echo 'All fields are required!';
 }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you simply use classical indexes with auto-increment, and set string "TS-" before the id with PHP or even better MySQL ?

[db-fiddle working example here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pfn62abgFWPcf2e68KFsRE/0)

**EDIT after our dialog in the comments below :**

```
SELECT CONCAT("TS-", LPAD(id_test, CHAR_LENGTH((SELECT MAX(id_test) FROM TEST)), '0')) AS trackingcode FROM TEST
```

[db-fiddle working example of an adaptative solution](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pfn62abgFWPcf2e68KFsRE/6)

So it is the fastest and cleanest way to achieve your goal.

When you'll have less than 10 rows, tracking_codes will be "TS-01", "TS-02" etc... When you'll have less than 100 rows they will be "TS-001", TS-002" etc...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189486/discussion-on-answer-by-phpnoob-auto-increment-trackingcode-column-every-inser).